# Minecraft Modding Errors (.java to .class compression errors)

Tags: java

Recently I started making a personal modpack. I ran into a block ID conflict and decided to fix it. I figured out how, and managed to change a .class file to .java so I was able to edit it. Now comes the issue.

When I try converting my files from .java to .class using the command prompt javac command, I get the following errors:

```
E:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\bettertools_164.s... error: '.' expected /* 3: */ import akc;

E:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\bettertools_164.s... error: ';' expected /* 3: */ import akc;

E:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\bettertools_164.s... error: class, interface, or enum expected /* 4: */ import aqz;

E:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\bettertools_164.s... error: '.' expected /* 5: */ import ard;

E\Users\Jeff\Desktop\bettertools_164.sr... error ';' expected /* 5: */ import ard;

E:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\bettertools_164\b... error: class, interface, or enum expected /* 6: */ import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistr...
```

I'm not sure if that is enough information to solve my problem, but thanks in advance to anyone able to answer it!

Comment: Why are you changing .java into .class?

Comment: In order for the mod to work correctly it must be in the .class form.

Comment: You can get the .class in the bin folder of Eclipse.

Comment: I haven't tried Eclipse yet, just the command prompt. I'll see how this goes tomorrow.

Comment: @Jordan I haven't been able to figure out Eclipse (really not a java programmer :( ), but I have decided that the mod is no longer necessary, and from what I've seen online, you solution would most likely work, so if you post this as an answer I can select it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the .class files of a java project look in your bin folder.

This should work for Eclipse and Netbeans.